# Why do my Roma tomatoes look like this?

Tags: houseplants, tomatoes, aphids

I basically just planted this plant and let it grow all summer more or less untended. It's become extremely viney, and has a ton of aphids. We live in a very dry area, near Sacramento, and I'm curious what might be the cause of some if not most of the fruit coming out with this splotchy yellow interior[image]

Comment: You forgot to include the second photo. Also my tomatoes do the same things in fall (and I think it is caused by insects, but I'll look for a good answer of this question. In any case in summer the tomatoes are fine, it is just late summer/fall problem).

Comment: I had this last year.  I thought it was all the stink bugs all over my plants.  Here in Ohio, those pests were awful.

Comment: My Amish Pastes are acting similarly now. (I'm in central NY). It seems to be only the fruits in contact with the ground that are doing it. Not sure why. Maybe they weren't getting enough sunlight to ripen fully, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this issue over the last two years in Ohio.  I have eliminated white flies, and aphids from my suspects.  I am pretty sure the damage I have experiences is from stink bugs.

Comment: In retrospect I believe that was probably it. I would add this link to a Deep Look video that looks into stink bugs, and it makes sense for sure.

 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8y2XmjdXqw

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to close this discussion, I noticed that my tomatoes that grew in contact with the concrete below them (have only a small plot of dirt and they grew over onto the cement) had blotchy skins like this, which on further examination extended through most of the flesh of the tomato. I don't yet know why this is the case but when compared to the other tomatoes from the vine that climbed up the wire fence, this definitely seems to be the cause.

Also, I had a crazy aphid problem, so there is that too.